# When accessing dict in another module its showing empty Python

Tags: python, dictionary, module

I'm trying to update a value in a dict defined in `File1.py` from another script, `File2.py`. However, when I call `getUserDict('123')` in `File2.py`, I get a "KeyError." I debugged this code, and the dict is apparently empty - how can I fix this?

Here's my code:

File1.py

```
import file2
user_dict = {}

class User:
    def __init__(self, chat_id):
        self.chat_id = chat_id
        self.refer_count = None
        self.wallet = None
        self.message_id = None
        self.total_amount = None
        self.first_name = None
        self.who_invite = None
        self._id = None
        self.trnx_id = None

def add_data():
      user = User('123')
      user.chat_id = '123'
      user.who_invite = '012'
      user.refer_count = 0
      user.total_amount = 0.0
      user.first_name = 'user'
      user_dict['123'] = user
      file2.print_chat_id()

def getUserDict(chat_id):
    return user_dict[chat_id]


add_data()
```

File2.py

```
import File1

def print_chat_id():
  user = File1.getUserDict('123') #Here is an error that File1 dict is empty (key error)
  print(user.chat_id)
```

Comment: You never call `add_data`?

Comment: i called it in main

Comment: Can you share "main"?

Comment: i updated my question with main function

Comment: `__name__ == '__main__'` will only be `True` if the file is run not when it's imported, that `if` block is not run. You need to call `add_data` some other way

Comment: What command are you using to run these files? You have a circular import, each file imports the other and this is a problem, you should restructure your code so this doesn't happen

Comment: @IainShelvington that's the problem. how can fix it any example

Answer (score 0):

`if __name__ == '__main__'` only runs when running in the same file, not imported, so you need to remove it:

```
import file2
user_dict = {}

class User:
    def __init__(self, chat_id):
        self.chat_id = chat_id
        self.refer_count = None
        self.wallet = None
        self.message_id = None
        self.total_amount = None
        self.first_name = None
        self.who_invite = None
        self._id = None
        self.trnx_id = None

def add_data():
      user = User('123')
      user.chat_id = '123'
      user.who_invite = '012'
      user.refer_count = 0
      user.total_amount = 0.0
      user.first_name = 'user'
      user_dict['123'] = user

def getUserDict(chat_id):
    return user_dict[chat_id]

add_data()
```

Comment: now look at my code